# How QuickFixJ submits order to an exchange

Tags: quickfixj

In the QuickFixJ source code, which class/method is responsible for actually sending a trade order to the exchange?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look in the quickfix.Session class. This method is used to send all messages (not just trades).